# jquery 1.9 upgrade - change in focus event

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.9, jquery-migrate

Can I blindly replace my `.trigger("focus")` with `$("selector").get(0).focus()` according this article?

**[Order of triggered "focus" events](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#order-of-triggered-quot-focus-quot-events)**.

Comment: I did, i didnt see any error with the new one, i have a jquery migrate file too, not sure if that is supressing any possible error

Comment: is it working fine after Replace?

Comment: seems so, im not totally sure, trying to test extensively

Comment: Test it dont worry ,it wont blow your computer,First test  it then post on Stackoverflow whats wrong in it